# I need to build a spreadsheet-like control in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, spreadsheet

I need to build a spreadsheet-like control in WPF. It does not need to have all the functionality of Excel.

It needs to format text

It needs to be able to merge cells together

It needs to have pagination

The form needs to be editable

The text in each cell needs to be Drag and Dropable

No numeric calculation is necessary

It needs to neatly print to printers

I need an idea of where to begin to implement this control. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You have a variety of options:

- Develop code yourself based on the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx)
- Use open source as a basis and adapt it to your needs: [Simple Spread Sheet](http://simplespreadsheet.codeplex.com/)
- Use a paid for option such as [SyncFusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/spreadsheet) (This is something I came across and I am in no way advertising or endorsing the product)

Given the complexity you may be best of actually paying for a product if the open source version is not suitable. Developing a control yourself will probably take a lot of time (~1+ weeks).

Comment: Hoffman: Isn't ListView a little dated? I thought DataGrid would be the way to go?

Comment: @Quinn: How in the world could a ListView be "dated"?